Extract Email from outlook using Logic app
I am trying to extract all my email information such as ID, receivedDatetime, Internetmessageid, from, to, attachment, CC, BBC etc in a SQL Table. I created below flow using Logic app

{
"definition": {
    "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
    "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
    "triggers": {
        "Recurrence": {
            "type": "Recurrence",
            "recurrence": {
                "interval": 1,
                "frequency": "Day"
            }
        }
    },
    "actions": {
        "Get_emails_(V3)": {
            "type": "ApiConnection",
            "inputs": {
                "host": {
                    "connection": {
                        "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365-1']['connectionId']"
                    }
                },
                "method": "get",
                "path": "/v3/Mail",
                "queries": {
                    "importance": "Any",
                    "fetchOnlyWithAttachment": false,
                    "folderPath": "Id::AAMkADU1NzM2NmJiLWUzOGItNDlmZS1iNjc3LWFkYzIzYmMzY2M4NgAuAAAAAAA8vBvBB693S5_H10o_0OuyAQD3AekO3P8LQpKHquyOHAMyAAAAAAEMAAA=",
                    "fetchOnlyUnread": false,
                    "fetchOnlyFlagged": false,
                    "includeAttachments": false,
                    "top": 25
                }
            },
            "runAfter": {},
            "metadata": {
                "Id::AAMkADU1NzM2NmJiLWUzOGItNDlmZS1iNjc3LWFkYzIzYmMzY2M4NgAuAAAAAAA8vBvBB693S5_H10o_0OuyAQD3AekO3P8LQpKHquyOHAMyAAAAAAEMAAA=": "Inbox"
            }
        },
        "For_each": {
            "type": "Foreach",
            "foreach": "@body('Get_emails_(V3)')?['value']",
            "actions": {
                "Insert_row_(V2)": {
                    "type": "ApiConnection",
                    "inputs": {
                        "host": {
                            "connection": {
                                "name": "@parameters('$connections')['sql']['connectionId']"
                            }
                        },
                        "method": "post",
                        "body": {
                            "ReceivedDateTime": "",
                            "HasAttachments": "",
                            "InternetMessageID": ""
                        },
                        "path": "/v2/datasets/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('****'))},@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('***'))}/tables/@{encodeURIComponent(encodeURIComponent('[POC].[OutlookEmailData]'))}/items"
                    }
                }
            },
            "runAfter": {
                "Get_emails_(V3)": [
                    "Succeeded"
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "outputs": {},
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "type": "Object",
            "defaultValue": {}
        }
    }
},
"parameters": {
    "$connections": {
        "value": {
            "office365-1": {
                "id": "***",
                "connectionId": "**",
                "connectionName": "office365-1"
            },
            "sql": {
                "id": "**",
                "connectionId": "***",
                "connectionName": "sql-6",
                "connectionProperties": {
                    "authentication": {
                        "type": "ManagedServiceIdentity",
                        "identity": "
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

}
Using GetMail(V3) action, i can only extract max of 25 records as it is the maximum limit. I have more than 1000 mails. How can i extract all of them. Can someone help me on this.

You can use Do Until loop and place Get emails (V3) in it to achieve this

@IkhtesamAfrin I tried below method, I am able to extract more than 25 records but it keep on loading the same top 25 records.

You can add the search query in Get Emails action which will be based on top and skip

How can i use Skip function in my case?

Add it in Get Emails actions by enabling additional property

You mean i will have a Skip parameter. I don't see any skip parameter in Get Email(v3) action.

You need to add top and skip here

We already have top parameter in Get EmaiI where the limit is 25 (i.e.)Top 25 emails. I tried Using skip function in Search query. Initially Initialize a variable Skipcounter as integer and  used expression in Search query - skip= @variables('SkipCounter'). After the Insert SQL. Setting the increment variable Skipcounter = Batchsize which is 25. But not getting desired output

You can fetch more than 25 emails by using the below flow.

Here Do Until loop is executing on greaterOrEquals(variables('TotalFetched'),variables('TargetCount')) condition.
Code-
{
    "definition": {
        "$schema": "https://schema.management.azure.com/providers/Microsoft.Logic/schemas/2016-06-01/workflowdefinition.json#",
        "contentVersion": "1.0.0.0",
        "triggers": {
            "When_a_HTTP_request_is_received": {
                "type": "Request",
                "kind": "Http"
            }
        },
        "actions": {
            "BatchSize": {
                "runAfter": {},
                "type": "InitializeVariable",
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "BatchSize",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 25
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "TotalFetched": {
                "runAfter": {
                    "BatchSize": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable",
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "TotalFetched",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 0
                        }
                    ]
                }
            },
            "Until": {
                "actions": {
                    "Get_emails_(V3)": {
                        "type": "ApiConnection",
                        "inputs": {
                            "host": {
                                "connection": {
                                    "name": "@parameters('$connections')['office365']['connectionId']"
                                }
                            },
                            "method": "get",
                            "path": "/v3/Mail",
                            "queries": {
                                "importance": "Any",
                                "fetchOnlyWithAttachment": false,
                                "folderPath": "Inbox",
                                "fetchOnlyUnread": false,
                                "fetchOnlyFlagged": false,
                                "includeAttachments": false,
                                "top": 25
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    "Increment_variable": {
                        "runAfter": {
                            "Get_emails_(V3)": [
                                "Succeeded"
                            ]
                        },
                        "type": "IncrementVariable",
                        "inputs": {
                            "name": "TotalFetched",
                            "value": "@variables('BatchSize')"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "runAfter": {
                    "TargetCount": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "expression": "@greaterOrEquals(variables('TotalFetched'),variables('TargetCount'))",
                "limit": {
                    "count": 60,
                    "timeout": "PT1H"
                },
                "type": "Until"
            },
            "TargetCount": {
                "runAfter": {
                    "TotalFetched": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                },
                "type": "InitializeVariable",
                "inputs": {
                    "variables": [
                        {
                            "name": "TargetCount",
                            "type": "integer",
                            "value": 100
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "outputs": {},
        "parameters": {
            "$connections": {
                "type": "Object",
                "defaultValue": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "parameters": {
        "$connections": {
            "value": {
                "office365": {
                    "id": "/subscriptions/0e89****e7c/providers/Microsoft.Web/locations/eastus2/managedApis/office365",
                    "connectionId": "/subscriptions/0e8*****b5e7c/resourceGroups/DefaultResourceGroup/providers/Microsoft.Web/connections/office365",
                    "connectionName": "office365"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

Loop executes 4 times to fetch 100 emails.

